# Getting size of vector using boost::mpl

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to compile this code & i am new to generic programing.Intention is to gets size of vector in boost::mpl. 
Trying my hand in boost::mpl. I am clueless why this code is not compliling.

error: 'type' in class 'vectorsum >' does not name a type

```
#include <boost/mpl/distance.hpp>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/begin_end.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/deref.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/greater_equal.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_back.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/times.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_back.hpp>

using namespace boost::mpl;

template <typename Seq>
struct vectorsum_impl
{
    typedef typename boost::mpl::begin<Seq>::type typestart;
    typedef typename boost::mpl::end<Seq>::type  typeend;
    typedef typename boost::mpl::distance<typestart,typeend>::type half_size;
};

template <typename S>
struct vectorsum: vectorsum_impl<S> {};

typedef boost::mpl::vector_c<int, 1, 2, 3, 4> testVec;
typedef vectorsum<testVec>::type testVec2;

main()
{
}
```

Comment: why don't you use [`boost::mpl::size`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/size.html)?

Comment: typedef typename boost::mpl::size<Seq>::type size it failed to compile with same error

Comment: typedef boost::mpl::vector_c<int, 1, 2, 3, 4> testVec;
typedef vectorsum<testVec>::type testVec2;

 whats wrong here, why its not compiling ??

Comment: read the documentation, you need to access `boost::mpl::size<Seq>::value`

Comment: In your original example your `vectorsum` (via `vectorsum_impl`) has three associated types and only those three: `typestart`, `typeend` and `half_size`. You are trying to access `type` which does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the size of a boost MPL sequence, I'd suggest using [`boost::mpl::size`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/size.html):

```
#include <boost/mpl/size.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector_c.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::mpl::vector_c<int, 1, 2, 3, 4> testVec;
    std::cout << boost::mpl::size<testVec>::value;
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
4
```

[live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UBMKtcvWR38HfTwP)